# What are SCARY iterators?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading the [VC11 Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140215050025/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx) on VC11's C++11 features when I've come up to the SCARY iterators topic.

**What are SCARY iterators and how does this affect my C++ coding experience?**

Comment: They are described in [n2980](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2980.pdf) and [n2911](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2911.pdf). Have you read those papers?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx

Comment: See that blog entry, from the Visual C++ team: [What Are SCARY Iterators?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx)

Comment: I always wished that `std::vector<T>::iterator` would be a plain old `T*`. There is nothing SCARYer than that.

Comment: @Irineau 'Of course' the URL broke; the article moved to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/what-are-scary-iterators/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're *using* them, there's no need to get SCAREd... just ignore their SCARY-ness.

If you're *making* them, that means you have to make your iterators independent of the container's allocator type, and of other generic parameters to the container that don't affect the iterators.

Comment: Out of curiosity, for any given object with a non-default allocator, or where there's the possibility that an object will have a non-default allocator, wouldn't it be better to use `decltype` instead of relying on whether your compiler implements SCARY iterators?  For example, if you for some reason create a `std::vector<int, std::allocator<std::string>> vTerribleIdea`, `decltype(vTerribleIdea)::iterator` will expand to the correct iterator, regardless of whether the iterator is tied to the allocator or not.  [See http://ideone.com/MLHhCa , or run it through MSVC for something more readable. ]

Comment: I can see how SCARY iterators are useful for pre-existing code, and allow the compiler to handle the code properly without it having to be rewritten to account for non-default iterators, but are they unnecessary when writing new, type-independent code because of `decltype`, or is there some benefit to using SCARY behaviour over explicitly specifying the iterator type with `decltype` that I'm not aware of?  [Not counting compilers that aren't C++11-compliant, they generally won't support either SCARY iterators or `decltype`.]

Answer (score 7):

From the linked PDF, at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2911.pdf

The acronym SCARY describes assignments and initializations that are Seemingly erroneous (appearing Constrained by conflicting generic parameters), but Actually work with the Right implementation (unconstrained bY the conflict due to minimized dependencies).

Comment: +0.5 for the reference (though links are not answers). +0.5 for quoting the backronym (though it's not very explanatory without further context). -1 for not answering the question.