# decltype of boost::make_zip_iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I have the following code:

```
std::vector<PriceQuote, tbb::scalable_allocator<PriceQuote> > cBids(maxSize);
std::vector<PriceQuote, tbb::scalable_allocator<PriceQuote> > cAsks(maxSize);

auto zipBidsAsks = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(cBids.begin(), cAsks.begin()));
```

If I wanted to `decltype` the return value so that instead of storing it in an `auto` I can store it in a `decltype` of whatever `boost::make_zip_iterator` returns. What does that code look like?

I have tried:

```
typedef decltype(boost::make_zip_iterator(std::vector<PriceQuote>, std::vector<PriceQuote>)) zipper_type;

// type referred to by zipper_type::iterator
typedef std::iterator_traits<zipper_type::iterator>::value_type zipped_type;

 zipped_type zipBidsAsks = boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(cBids.begin(), cAsks.begin()));
```

But that doesn't even come close to working. Finally, if I want to iterate over `zipBidsAsks` and get each `<0>`, `<1>`. How is that done?

The access code now gives an error:

```
    struct PriceBookEventData
{
    timeval ts;
    unsigned totalSize;
    unsigned maxSize;


    typedef decltype
    (
         boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::tuple<std::vector<PriceQuote>::iterator,
                                               std::vector<PriceQuote>::iterator>())
    ) zipper_type;

     zipper_type zipBidsAsks;
};

void AGUI::HandlePriceBookChange(const PriceBookEventData pbed)
{
int k = 0;

while(0 != stop--)
{
    PriceQuote pqb = boost::get<0>(pbed.zipBidsAsks[k]);
    PriceQuote pqa = boost::get<1>(pbed.zipBidsAsks[k]);


/data/cbworkspace/AGUI/AGUI.cpp|101|error: no matching function for call to ‘get(boost::detail::operator_brackets_result<boost::zip_iterator<boost::tuples::tuple<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PriceQuote*, std::vector<PriceQuote> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PriceQuote*, std::vector<PriceQuote> > > >, boost::tuples::cons<PriceQuote&, boost::tuples::cons<PriceQuote&, boost::tuples::null_type> >, boost::tuples::cons<PriceQuote&, boost::tuples::cons<PriceQuote&, boost::tuples::null_type> > >::type)’|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to figure out the type using `decltype` instead of `auto`, the latter was designed specifically for cases like this one. Using `decltype` instead is cumbersome.

You were close with what you tried, except you gave `boost::make_zip_iterator` a pair of vectors, instead of a `tuple` of vector interators.

Try this instead

```
typedef decltype(
  boost::make_zip_iterator(
    boost::tuple<
      std::vector<PriceQuote>::iterator, 
      std::vector<PriceQuote>::iterator>()
  ) 
) zipper_type;
```

As for iterating over the zip iterator, here's a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iterator/zip_iterator.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4}, v2{10,20,30,40};

    std::for_each(
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.begin(), v2.begin())),
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.end(), v2.end())),
        []( boost::tuple<int, int> const& tup ) {
            std::cout 
              << boost::get<0>(tup) 
              << ", " 
              << boost::get<1>(tup) 
              << std::endl;
        }
    );
}
```

Output:

```
1, 10
2, 20
3, 30
4, 40
```

Comment: Thank you, when I use your code in my code [boost version 1.49], I get this error: /usr/local/include/boost/tuple/detail/tuple_basic.hpp|310|error: no matching function for call to ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PriceQuote*, std::vector<PriceQuote> >::__normal_iterator(const stored_head_type&)’|

Comment: @user1676605 I can't [reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=53dbb532d4ea03627fbdfd41707e2dc4-f6dd968dbc09ccca850bc160d430b00a) the error. But I'm not using a non-default vector allocator in my example. Maybe your libstdc++ implementation is not using [scary iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391705/what-are-scary-iterators), so you need to include the allocator type also in the `decltype` expression. Try replacing `std::vector<PriceQuote>::iterator` with `std::vector<PriceQuote, tbb::scalable_allocator<PriceQuote> >::iterator`

Comment: Praetorian, that was exactly the problem. Adding the additional tbb works. Now I have a new problem iterating over the zip.

Comment: If someone could help with the final error. See access section, the very end of original post.

Comment: @user1676605 `zipBidsAsks` is a tuple containing 2 elements, both of which are of type `PriceQuote`. `tuple` doesn't implement `operator[]` so `pbed.zipBidsAsks[k]` won't compile. I think what you want is `PriceQuote pqb = boost::get<0>(pbed.zipBidsAsks);`

Comment: ? zipBidAsks is two elements not of PriceQuote, but iterators of tuple  of PriceQuote ?

Comment: @user1676605 No it isn't; look at the example I linked to in the comment above. In that, within the `for_each` loop, `boost::get<0>(tup)` returns a `PriceQuote&`, which is why I can access the data member `i` as `boost::get<0>(tup).i`

Comment: if I say std::for_each(zipper_type& t = pbed.zipBidsAsks)
    {

        PriceQuote pqb = t.get<0>();
        PriceQuote pqa = t.get<1>(); } I get an error /AGUI.cpp|96|error: expected primary-expression before ‘&’ token|

Comment: @user1676605 That's because you can't just invent syntax and hope for it to work! I feel like you're not even looking at the examples above. [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) requires 3 arguments, a start iterator, an end iterator and a function that can be called with the result of dereferencing the iterator; it operates over the range *[start, end)*; you've given it a single iterator argument, which is not possible to iterate over. Also, you can't declare a variable within the `for_each` expression.

Comment: – Praetorian, I finally decided to rework my program to look like yours. Now I can get it to compile and your example was very valuable. I would still like to know how to get my original example to work, but I am going to sideline that until I get more c++11 experience. Thank you!

Comment: -Praetorian, is there a non lambda version of std::for_each(
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.begin(), v2.begin())),
        boost::make_zip_iterator(boost::make_tuple(v1.end(), v2.end())),
        []( boost::tuple<int, int> const& tup )

Comment: @user1676605 Sure, create a struct, say `struct zip_getter`, and define `zip_getter::operator()(boost::tuple<int, int> const& tup) const` and do what you want to in this operator. Pass an instance of this struct to `for_each`

Comment: -Praetorian, I should have been more clear, is there a version that does not use std::for_each. The reason is that there is no clean way to exit the loop in the middle of it, AFAIK.

Comment: @user1676605 Write a plain old `for` loop?