# const tuple - but able to change content (references)?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, reference

I have defined a (const) tuple as follows:

```
double var1, var2;
const tuple<double&, double&> my_tup(var1, var2);
```

Now, why am I able to do the following:

```
get<0>(my_tup) = 3215.513
```

The above code would only make sense if the references contained in the tuple are `const` pointers to var1 and var2 - the memory address itself is `const` (because the tuple is `const`, so we cannot change any of its contents), but the contents of the memory addresses pointed to, not, hence the allowed change. But, if you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) discussion about what references really are, you will see there are some fervent advocates for the reference not being a `const` pointer, but just a different name for a variable already declared. In that case, how can I interpret a `const` tuple of references? Is declaring the tuple as `const` above, if it contains references, pointless then?

(Note that I had to use a `const` tuple in another setting, which is too complicated to explain and irrelevant to the question.)

Comment: I may be remembering incorrectly, but tuples might be required to use `std::reference_wrapper` for reference-typed elements, in which case the elements would be const pointers to non-const.

Comment: Ah, what I was thinking of was `make_tuple`, where giving it a `reference_wrapper` (e.g., from `ref` or `cref`) will deduce a reference type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a class object is `const`, then its data members are implicitly `const` too (unless declared `mutable`). So, in general, if a tuple is `const`, then none of its members can be modified.

However, a reference cannot be `const` (only the referenced type can be). Indeed, a reference itself cannot be modified anyway (any attempt to do so modifies the object referred to). Since a reference cannot be `const`, the members of your `const` tuple still have type `double&`, not `const double&`, and the `const` on your `tuple` is pretty meaningless in this case. What you really want is `tuple<const double&, const double&>`.

Comment: Ok, so it is pointless to declare a tuple as const then. It was actually from this discussion [Inline Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982214/decltype-of-boostmake-zip-iterator) that I got the example. If you look at the boost::tuple argument to the lambda function (within the for_each function) in the answer to the OP's question, you will see the tuple is declared `const`. It does not compile otherwise, leaving me to think that the boost::zip_iterator returns a `const` tuple when dereferenced.

Comment: But in any case, I actually want to be able to modify the contents of the tuple (actually, the stuff that the references point to) so I will keep the template arguments to the tuple as is.

Comment: @KonradKapp I assume the lambda takes a const reference because that's a very common idiom in C++, not because another function returns a `const` object by value (which is very rare, as far as I know)

Comment: so, if I have a `const tuple<int, int>`, then the reason I cannot modify its members is not because the member types are now `const int` by implication, but because it prohibits me from modifying members by its own mechanism? In other words, members are still of type `int` in the example above, but the tuple still disallows me to modify? Actually I've noticed you get a different error message when trying to modify `const tuple` members from the usual messages received when modifying `const`, so that's probably why.

Comment: In addendum to my comment above, the `const tuple` disallows me from changing what the reference "points to" (for lack of a better term), but it cannot change what it points to anyway, hence the pointless effort? Also, with regards to what you mentioned on lambda taking a `const` reference, how can it still take a `const` reference, if I explicitly defined the argument to the lambda to not be a `const` reference (in the case that it did not compile)?

Comment: @KonradKapp If you have `const tuple<int, int>` then the members implicitly have type `const int`, so that's why you can't modify them. The tuple doesn't have a special mechanism to prevent it.

Comment: @KonradKapp Regarding references, you are basically correct: you can't reseat a reference under any circumstances. As for your other question, I don't understand. If you write a function taking a non-`const` reference, it will not accept an argument that is a `const` reference.

Comment: ok, but it beats me then why the `const tuple<double &, double &>` members do not have type `const double &` (instead of `double & const`, as I understand from your original answer). With regards to the lambda I mentioned earlier, sorry, my wording was a bit bad there: You mentioned earlier that you assume that the lambda takes a const reference, but the whole reason I had to work with a `const tuple` here, was that when I defined my lambda to take a non-`const` reference, it did not compile. (continued in next comment)

Comment: It only compiled when it was declared `const`, which led me to think that the iterator returned by boost::make_zip_iterator, returns `const` references, when dereferenced, because the lambda function only wanted to accept `const` references.

Comment: In any case, my apologies for my lengthy questions and ruthless interrogation. Haha I am quite eager to learn the nitty gritty things of the language when I can, so thank you for you patience.

Comment: @Brain, also, my apologies for the `double & const` thing I posted in the comment above, could not change the comment after 5 minutes...will just delete it later...but by it I meant the non-existing `const` reference as you put it in you original answer

Comment: @Brain, if you are still reading this, I have found a description of the `zip_iterator` class, and I am assuming that `get_iterator_tuple()` is the function that gets called when "dereferencing" the iterator in the for_each loop. The `get_iterator_tuple()` is indeed declared as returning a `const IteratorTuple&`, explaining why the lambda function had to be declared with a `const` parameter (if I am correct).

Comment: @Brain, if you are interested, the description of the `zip_iterator` class is [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91438/discussion-between-brian-and-konrad-kapp).