# operator==() using template template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

---

**EDIT: *Prolog: I'm a victim of my own ignorance and also of late-night coding.***

---

I'm writing a templated class using template template.  It has an iterator, which means that I need to provide an appropriately templated `operator==()`. This is where I'm having trouble.

Representative code sample follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

namespace detail {
  template <typename T> class foo {};
  template <typename T> class bar {};
}

template <template<class> class A, template<class> class B>
struct basic_thing {
  template <typename T> using target_type = A<B<T>>;

  target_type<float> fmember;
  target_type<int>   imember;

  struct iterator {
    bool equal (const iterator& other) { return true; }
  };

  iterator begin () { return iterator{}; }
  iterator end   () { return iterator{}; }
};

template <template<class> class A, template<class> class B>
bool operator== (const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& lhs, const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& rhs) {
  return lhs.equal(rhs);
}

int main ()
{
  using Thing = basic_thing<detail::foo, detail::bar>;

  Thing t;
  cout << typeid(t.fmember).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(t.imember).name() << endl;

  bool b = (t.begin() == t.end());

  return 0;
}
```

My goal here is to provide a composable way to define `basic_thing::target_type`, and this pattern works for that purpose.  But, I'm stuck at how to declare `operator==()` for `basic_thing::iterator`.   Either this isn't very straightforward, or there's something obvious that I'm missing. (Likely the latter.)

g++-7.4.0 with `-std=c++11` produces the following:

```
foo.cc: In function 'int main()':
foo.cc:39:23: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'basic_thing<detail::foo, detail::bar>::iterator' and 'basic_thing<detail::foo, detail::bar>::iterator')
   bool b = (t.begin() == t.end());
             ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
foo.cc:27:6: note: candidate: template<template<class> class A, template<class> class B> bool operator==(const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator&, const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator&)
 bool operator== (const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& lhs, const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& rhs) {
      ^~~~~~~~
foo.cc:27:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
foo.cc:39:32: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'template<class> class A'
   bool b = (t.begin() == t.end());
                            ^
```

What are some correct ways to do this?  Is it even possible when template templates are involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler way is to create it inside the struct directly (as member or friend function):

```
template <template<class> class A, template<class> class B>
struct basic_thing {
  // ...
  struct iterator {
    bool equal (const iterator& other) { return true; }

    bool operator ==(const iterator& rhs) const;
    // friend bool operator ==(const iterator& lhs, const iterator& rhs);
  };
};
```

With

```
template <template<class> class A, template<class> class B>
bool operator== (const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& lhs,
                 const typename basic_thing<A, B>::iterator& rhs);
```

`A` and `B` are not deducible (on the left of `::`).

so only callable the ugly way:

```
bool b = operator==<detail::foo, detail::bar>(t.begin(), t.begin());
```

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing.  I have no explanation for this, but I somehow got it in my head that `operator==()` couldn't be used as class method.  No more late-night coding for me!

Comment: Also, [SCARY iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391705/what-are-scary-iterators) solves this quite nicely too: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13ffb554815a21f8