# What is the correct way of declaring an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am wondering if there is any difference between using

```
std::set<int,std::greater<int>>::iterator itr;
```

and

```
std::set<int>::iterator itr;
```

I tried the two of them in the code below and the result is the same, I would like know is there is any difference between one and the other or if there is any instance in which I should need to use one over the other (when using the STL library or another case).

CODE:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<set>

int main(){
    std::set<int,std::greater<int>> s1;
    s1.insert(40);
    s1.insert(30);
    s1.insert(60);
    s1.insert(20);
    s1.insert(50);
    s1.insert(10);
    // std::set<int>::iterator itr;
    std::set<int,std::greater<int>>::iterator itr;
    std::cout<<"\nThe set s1 is: \n";
    for(itr=s1.begin();itr!=s1.end();itr++){
        std::cout<<*itr<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: `std::set<int>::iterator itr;` is an error because `s1` is a `std::set<int, std::greater<int>>` and not a `std::set<int>`. The type of iterator you use must match the container's iterator type.

Comment: While not an answer to the question you present here, you may find that `auto itr=s1.begin()` is the most straightforward way to correctly declare this iterator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm doing it right now and it compiles.

Comment: @blueglass That is an unfortunate coincidence. In C++ it is a critical error to assume that compilation will fail if your code is incorrect or contains errors. Many categories of errors are not required to be caught by the compiler. Often the code will seem to compile but won't work as expected, or it will fail to compile or behave differently when you try it on a different compiler or platform.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ty.

Comment: Your standard library uses [SCARY iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14391705/5754656) (which the C++ standard doesn't force implementations to do, but it allows them)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::set<int>::iterator itr;` is wrong.

It happens to work on both GCC, Clang, and MSVC by default.
But e.g. if I enable GCC's iterator debugging (`-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`), it stops compiling.

Normally you don't need to manually spell the iterator type. You can do `for (auto itr = s1.begin(); ...)`. Or, if the iterator needs to be created uninitialized, `decltype(s1)::iterator itr;`.

Comment: Or better, just use a [range-based loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead and not deal with the iterators directly at all, eg: `for(int value : s1)`