# What is the problem when using a custom allocator in c++, when assigning the container to an iterator?

Tags: c++, gcc, iterator, allocator

I have the problem that GCC is complaining about a type mismatch when compiling the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

template <class T>
struct Mallocator {
    typedef T value_type;

    Mallocator() = default;

    template <class U>
    Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) {}

    T* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        if (n > std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / sizeof(T))
            throw "std::bad_array_new_length";

        if (auto p = static_cast<T*>(malloc(n * sizeof(T)))) {
            report(p, n);
            return p;
        }

        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n) {
        report(p, n, 0);
        free(p);
    }

   private:
    void report(T* p, std::size_t n, bool alloc = true) const {
        std::cout << (alloc ? "Alloc: " : "Dealloc: ") << sizeof(T) * n
                  << " bytes at " << std::hex << std::showbase
                  << reinterpret_cast<void*>(p) << std::dec << '\n';
    }
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int f): m_values{f} {}
    std::vector<int, Mallocator<int> > m_values;
    std::vector<int>::iterator begin() { return m_values.begin(); }
};

int main() {
    Foo f(1);
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC and Clang (with libc++ enabled) compile fine for the same code. Isn't there a problem, when the iterator hops to the next values? How can it know, where in memory is the next value to iterate, if the allocator allocates different sizes than the standard allocator?

Comment: The problem is that std::vector<int, Mallocator<int>>::iterator and std::vector<int,  std::allocator<int>>::iterator can be different types not required to be silently convertible to each other. Implementation has full right to make these convertible to each other or even same type. It is hard to understand how your follow up questions in the end of question are related to that problem.

Comment: I dont understand how this conversion can happen implicitly between two unrelated types. If i malloc a greater space than the standard allocator (lets say 11 bytes for an int) and return the iterator of vector<int, mallocator> to a standard iterator. Then how does next() work on the returned object? How does it know where the object is in memory?

Comment: A `vector` of size N contains N contiguously stored elements, and the first element is at the location returned from `allocate`. Iteration uses normal pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Read about ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391705/what-are-scary-iterators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<int>` is one type, `std::vector<int, Mallocator<int> >` is a different type. It is unspecified whether `std::vector<int, Mallocator<int> >::iterator` is convertible to `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

A simple way they could be incompatible is they are defined within `vector`, and so are themselves unrelated types.

A simple way they could be compatible is that they are defined outside `vector` and aliased within it, and only depend on the element type parameter.

The very simple fix is for `Foo` to use the correct type in it's declaration.

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int f): m_values{f} {}
    std::vector<int, Mallocator<int> > m_values;
    std::vector<int, Mallocator<int> >::iterator begin() { return m_values.begin(); }
};
```